# Kafka Connect Distributed mode The group coordinator is not available

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have been trying this for two weeks now, I am running Kafka cluster on separate machines than my connect nodes. I am unable to get connect running properly. I can read and write to kafka no issue. Zookeeper seems to be running fine.

I launch connect:

```
$ bin/connect-distributed connect-distributed.properties
```

Connect keeps looping through this error:

```
[2018-08-21 15:45:12,161] INFO [Worker clientId=c1, groupId=connect-cluster] Discovered group coordinator 172.25.1.2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:677)
[2018-08-21 15:45:12,163] INFO [Worker clientId=c1, groupId=connect-cluster] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:509)
[2018-08-21 15:45:12,165] INFO [Worker clientId=c1, groupId=connect-cluster] Group coordinator 172.25.1.2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:729)
[2018-08-21 15:45:12,266] INFO [Worker clientId=c1, groupId=connect-cluster] Discovered group coordinator 172.25.40.219:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:677)
[2018-08-21 15:45:12,267] INFO [Worker clientId=c1, groupId=connect-cluster] Group coordinator 172.25.1.2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:729)
```

Here is what my connect-distributed.properties looks like:

```
bootstrap.servers=172.25.1.2:9092,172.25.1.3:9092,172.25.1.4:9092
group.id=connect-cluster

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
offset.storage.partitions=3

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=3

status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.partitions=3

offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

rest.host.name=172.25.1.5
rest.port=8083

heartbeat.interval.ms=3000
session.timeout.ms=30000
security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
client.id=c1

plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

__Consumer_offsets topic looks like this:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic __consumer_offsets                                       
Topic:__consumer_offsets        PartitionCount:50       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=producer
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 2       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,2
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 3    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 4    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2.... etc
```

Comment: I don't think you should be setting `client.id` in the connect properties. At least it is not even mentioned in the property file https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/connect-distributed.properties

Comment: "The purpose of this is to be able to track the source of requests beyond just ip/port by allowing a logical application name to be included in server-side request logging."  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Comment: I do not think its what would be causing any issues, i have tried it without before hand without any luck.

Comment: @ldrrp - seems it is not able to discover the kafka node... so are your connect instance and kafka instance under same VPC?? because from config it seems you are using the private IP to reach the Kafka cluster

Comment: I have confirmed connection by telnet ipaddress port on each server. everything connects fine.

Comment: Even number of Zookeeper nodes? (http://bytecontinnum.com/2016/09/zookeeper-always-configured-odd-number-nodes/)

Comment: You mean odd number, and yes. as per the docs for a minimum cluster size i have 3.

Comment: At this point my team is building an elastic search kafka connector on Golang. Im not sure i can wait any longer before my director gets mad at me. I will keep trying other things though on the side for anyone who may be facing this issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing a connector in Go, I came across the same issue. I was forced to solve it myself.

When a connector connects to kafka it automatically writes to the topics and to `__offset_topics`. When a connector crashes, it leaves trace of itself in those tables as the coordinator. When a new connector starts up it finds the record in the table and attempts to communicate with the coordinator. The coordinator fails to respond and the connector never works.

You can fix this one of two ways, Delete all the topics (`connect-configs`, `connect-offsets`, `connect-status`, `__offset_topics`) and restart the cluster. The other method is to remove the coordinator from the topics, which I am currently unsure how to perform.

Comment: It's not really clear why `The coordinator fails to respond and the connector never works.` all of a sudden. Were you able to figure out what was the root issue? Sorry, I know it's almost 2 years now, but worth a shot :D

Answer (score 3):

Posting for others who might find it useful.

I had the same problem... and restarting kafka solved the problem in my case.

After executing:

```
service kafka status
```

Made my log to be fine in less than 10 seconds:

```
2019-11-08 14:30:19.781  INFO [-,,,] 1 --- [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=datasources-ca-contacts] Discovered group coordinator myserver:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
```

Comment: On minikube, i had to restart minikube cluster it and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the broker and restarting kafka did the work for me . Delete the kakfka-logs and zookeeper folder from **/tmp** folder in mac .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I ran out of disk space on my brokers.  Might be something worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause that mention @ldrrp is correct, but if you don't want or you can't delete the "offsets cache" you can use a new group for your consumer.

```
//before: original group cause error
props.put("group.id", "my_data_consumer");

//after: works for me
props.put("group.id", "my_data_consumer_2");
```

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting the brokers, This problem resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is something to do with the cluster congestion wherein the Abstract-Coordinator is unable to find a broker which is healthier and can take up Group Coordinator responsibility of a Consumer Group. If all the brokers are too busy, it keeps on searching in a loop until it finds a free broker.

Though this congestion can be due to multiple reasons, the root cause might differ w.r.t use-cases.

Restarting might help though it doesn't resolve the root problem. I guess tuning/bench-marking Consumer configuration is a better approach.

Answer (score -2):

add hostname of all kafka brokers to your /etc/hosts file, and try again

Comment: No, this is not the issue as im connecting via static ip's not hostname.